# Scanning Only A Column With Textscan

Tags: matlab, text-files, textscan

I want to take the second column of a real time changing text file by textscan command. I can only take the first column of the text file but I want the second column. Here is my code:

```
    fileid = fopen (Path);
    rxt = textscan (fileid, '%d %*[^\n]' );
    fclose (fileid);

    arr = rxt {1,1};
```

How can I modify this for reading only second column?

Here is some portion from text file:

```
226, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, 0,00, 0,00, 0,00
227, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, 0,00, 0,00, 0,00
228, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, -187500,02, 0,00, 0,00, 0,00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify that you'd like to discard the first number (`%*d`), keep the second `(%d)`, and discard the rest of the string (`%*[^\n]`)

```
textscan(fileid, '%*d, %d, %*[^\n]')
```

Based on the data though, you've pasted a comma-separted file that *also* uses `,` for the radix point. As such, you'll want to read in the second and third numbers and convert them into a floating point number

```
numbers = textscan(fileid, '%*d, %d,%d %*[^\n]');
numbers = arrayfun(@(a,b)a * 10^b, numbers{:})
```